# how to check if "params Expression" does not contain values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following repository method:-

```
public async Task<Skill> FindSkill(int id, params Expression<Func<Skill, object>>[] includeProperties)
{
    var query = context.Skills.AsQueryable();
    if (includeProperties != null )
        query = includeProperties.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
    return await query.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.SkillID == id);
}
```

and I call this method as follow:-

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Deactivate(int id, Byte[] timestamp = null)
{
    var skill = await unitofwork.SkillRepository.FindSkill(id);
    //snip
}
```

but I can not detect when I am not passing any `params Expression`, I tried also the following checks but did not work:-

```
includeProperties.Count() != 0 || includeProperties[0].Name == "0"
```

now I have noted that inside VS the following will be received when passing empty list:-

[image]

Comment: Does includeProperties.Length !=0 work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using params and not supplying any parameters for it. An empty array will be created. You should use includeProperties.Length !=0 as Nick Bailey suggests in his comment.